# What is the absolute fastest way to compare one large set of data to another?

Tags: database, sorting, dataset, compare

You have a big list of unique items (hundreds of thousands of lines). You want to see if those items exist in another set of data. That other set of data is just a file with items line by line, and are also a unique set of data. You can put any data in a db, use any programming language, etc.

What do you do to compare these the fastest? Only constraints are that the hardware is a normal server, not a db server. One spindle max.

C? Implementing sorting algorithms? DB for indexing etc?

**Admins took out the answer I went with "because the question is too broad": Bloom filters in python. It's really easy to implement with python's bloom filter library.**

Comment: There are too many ways to approach this problem. The answers would just turn into a straw-poll for which one people liked. The best thing is to do some research on the topic yourself, find two or three, _analyze_ them, determine if they work for you or not, and _try them out_. Come to us when you have a specific question about something you have attempted to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your "test" file has a resonable size, a quick solution is to build a hash map for every entry in that file. A C# solution (runs in Big O ( N )) is this:

```
public static bool SetIsPresentIn(string firstFileLocation, string secondFileLocation)
        {
            HashSet<string> set = new HashSet<string> ();

            using (var sr = new FileStream(firstFileLocation, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(sr))
                {
                    while (reader.EndOfStream == false )
                    {
                        var text = reader.ReadLine();
                        set.Add(text);
                    }
                }
            }

            // iterating through the first one!

            using (var secondFile = new FileStream(secondFileLocation, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(secondFile))
                {
                    while (reader.EndOfStream == false)
                    {
                        var line = reader.ReadLine();
                        // perform a lookup!

                        if (set.Remove(line) && set.Count == 0)
                            return true;

                    }
                }
            }

            return set.Count == 0;
        }
```

Otherwise I would do a clever thing: split your "test" file in file partitions: each partition name matches a hash code for each line. When iterating over second file, just create a hash code and search inside the coresponding partition that was built from the first file!

Example:

```
public static bool SetIsPresentInUsingFilePartitions(string firstFileLocation, string secondFileLocation, string partitionsRootLocation)
        {
            Dictionary<int, StreamWriter> partitionWriters = new Dictionary<int, StreamWriter>();

            Dictionary<int, string> locations = new Dictionary<int, string>();
            using (var sr = new FileStream(secondFileLocation, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(sr))
                {
                    while (reader.EndOfStream == false)
                    {
                        var text = reader.ReadLine();
                        var hCode = text.GetHashCode();


                        var fileName = Path.Combine(partitionsRootLocation, hCode.ToString ());

                        if (false == partitionWriters.ContainsKey(hCode))
                        {
                            var fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
                            partitionWriters[hCode] = new StreamWriter(fs);
                            locations[hCode] = fileName;
                        }

                        partitionWriters[hCode].WriteLine(text);
                    }
                }
            }

            // close writers 
            foreach (var item in partitionWriters)
                item.Value.Dispose();


            using (var sr = new FileStream(firstFileLocation, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(sr))
                {
                    while (reader.EndOfStream == false)
                    {
                        var line = reader.ReadLine();
                        var hCode = line.GetHashCode();

                        string location;
                        if (false == locations.TryGetValue(hCode, out location))
                        {
                            return false; // tere's a line that is not found in the second file!

                        }

                        var found = false;
                        using (var file = new FileStream(location, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                        {
                            using (var fs = new StreamReader(file))
                            {
                                while (fs.EndOfStream == false)
                                {
                                    var firstFileLine = fs.ReadLine();
                                    if (line == firstFileLine)
                                    {
                                        found = true;
                                        break;
                                    }

                                }
                            }


                        }

                        if (!found)
                            return false;
                    }
                }

            }

            return true;

        }
```

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking of something similar in my mind but had never implemented such a thing. It helps to see it printed out.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a simple bash script:

First sort the lists

```
$ sort list1.txt > list1.sorted.txt
$ sort list2.txt > list2.sorted.txt
```

Then do a join to find the common elements for both lists:

```
$ join -1 1 -2 1 list1.sorted.txt list2.sorted.txt
```

This should be relatively fast and has a low memory consumption.

Comment: Is this comparable to python and set()? If so, I'm trying to go faster.

Comment: It is likely going to be faster than python, however, it is not necessarily the fastest solution. This method doesn't use a large amount of memory, however, that might not be an issue if your records are not very wide. You will have to run some benchmarks to find out which is the fasted method on your hardware.

Comment: The bloom filter implementation in python was easy to get going and test. See above!

Comment: I have seen the answer.  The Bloomberg filter is probabilistic though and not deterministic and false positives are possible. You are trading accuracy for speed.